# TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json' - PYTHON,AWS

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elasticsearch

Is there anyone here who can help me with this python script.

When I execute this script I am getting this error:

**TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'**

```
import boto3
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

host = 'XXXXX' # include https:// and trailing /
region = 'ap-northeast-1'
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

# Register repository

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
path = '_snapshot/XXXXX' # the Elasticsearch API endpoint
url = host + path

payload = {
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "XXXXX",
    "region": "ap-northeast-1",
    "role_arn": "XXXXX"
  }
}



r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: json is not an argument to the put method. The correct argument to use is data

Comment: I tried it but it returned this error:

{"Message":"Your request: '/_snapshot/CuratorRepo' is not allowed due to invalid input parameters."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just `r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, headers=headers)`. Looks like don't need argument json=payload because headers includes that json format. More information here (https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2664) may also be helpful.

Comment: Justin, 
 I tried your suggestion and it worked. Thank you so much

Comment: That’s great! Can you please select my check mark as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Amazon Linux/2.8.1 (and probably other releases) have requests==1.2.3 installed by default. According to the [release notes](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) for the requests module, the 'json' parameter was only added in 2.4.2 (2014-10-05)

You can check your installed version and upgrade to the latest version like so:

```
$ pip show requests | grep Version
Version: 1.2.3

$ sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade requests

$ pip show requests | grep Version
Version: 2.8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the exact same thing as the question here, and had the same requests=1.2.3 library version issues.

The accepted answer did not work for me, as no surprise, since it doesn t send any payload at all.

What did work was using the 1.2.3 "data" argument and feeding it the json payload object as a string:

```
...
import json
...
r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```